# Error While Fetching db using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have Tried to fetch data from MySQL db using eloquent in my laravel application it shows Parse Error  here my code :

**Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class design extends Model {
     //Table Name
     protected $table='designs';
     //Primary key
     public $primarykey='id';
     // TimeStamp
     public $timestamps=true; 
}
```

**Controller Page:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\design;

class designController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $design=design::all();
        //$design = design::select('Design No','Design Name','Chain Weight/Length','status')->where('status','=','Active')->get();
        return view('pages.design')->with('design',$design);
    }
}
```

**page for listing:**
the error occurring while using for-each

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

    @section('content')
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <h2 class="text-center">Designs</h2>
                    @if(count($design)>=1)
                    <h2>Done</h2>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Design No</th>
                                        <th>Design Name</th>
                                        <th>Weight/Lenght</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                @foreach($design as $design)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$design->Design No}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$design->Design Name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$design->Chain Weight/Length}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">{{$design->status}}</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection
```

Comment: Please also include your modal code

Comment: @bluemoon I added that code above

Comment: what is Design No , Design Name these should be as design_no , design_name in your DB did't read with space

Comment: and also try to make difference in `foreach($design as $new_design)`

Comment: Design no and design Name are column names@bluemoon

Comment: Ya i tried that also have same error : ** ErrorException
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'No' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' (View: /var/www/html/proj_gold/resources/views/pages/design.blade.php)**

Comment: it doesn't allow space it should be in lower cases as design_no , design_name in your DB

Comment: 1st of all check in your controller index after query dd($design). is it returns any output ??

Comment: Ya thanks @bluemoon rename the column works for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152982/discussion-between-harish-karthick-and-blue-moon).

Comment: Should i answer if you will accepts? others will also be able to get help?

Comment: can you change your controller design to designs and on you for each use design and if I was you i would rethink about naming my class as well. think like small case for class name and if your table is called designs you dont have to let laravel know the table name.

Comment: ya Make this as an answer @bluemoon it will help others

Comment: @bluemoon  can you pls help this qustion [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929807/laravel-to-get-db-values-from-session-id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't allow space in column name it should be in lower cases as **design_no , design_name** in your DB

and then fetch as

```
    @foreach($design as $new_designs)

    <td>{{$new_designs->design_no }}</td>
    // and so on
   @endforeach
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

{{$design->{'Design No'} }}

Answer (score 0):

Yous should try this:

**Controller Page**

```
public function index()
{
  //
  $designs=design::all();

  return view('pages.design',compact('designs'));
}
```

**View Page**

```
@foreach($designs as $design)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$design->Design_No}}</td>
    <td>{{$design->Design_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{$design->Chain_Weight/Length}}</td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">{{$design->status}}</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```