# Laravel to get db values from session id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to create a session and retrieve it and get db values using the session id

(i.e) While on click edit i like to store the data-id in session and from session id i like to retrieve the db values using Eloquent

so far i stored and retrieve the session the only problem i don't know to get db from that session id here is my following code

**My ajax call :**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.editaction').click(function(){
       var editaction=($(this).attr("data-id"));
       console.log(editaction);
       $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                 }
                });
       $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"/design_session",
         data:"design_id="+editaction,
         success:function(results){
         window.location.href="/design_edit";
              }
            }); 
        });
    })
```

**Db controller page :**

```
public function show()
{
    $design_id = $request->session()->get('design_id');
    return view('pages.design_edit')->with('design',$design_id);
}
```

**so far i am getting redirect to another page successfully but i don't how to invoke or pass the ajax through the function to get db values**

Comment: Are yo getting id from session ?

Comment: @bluemoon I think the session is stored correctly ,so only i redirect to the another page but the only thing is that i don't know is that  function is  correctly called or not

Comment: You need to check 1st as `dd($design_id)` before return

Comment: @bluemoon thanks  for response the following code helped me   
I resolved The problem   

**
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $design_id = $request->session()->get('design_id');
        $designView = design::find($design_id);
        return view('pages.design_edit')->with('design',$designView);
    }**